# Speeding up frame averaging and Video Writing, For loop

Tags: matlab, image-processing, for-loop

I have a code that alters frames by averaging them and then writes the altered frames into an avi file. I'm using two for loops which I believe is slowing down the process. Here is a portion of my code below:

```
 for ii= 1:numel(frame)
     avgframe=plus(avgframe,str2double(frame{ii}));
 end

 avgframe=avgframe/(numel(frame));

 for jj= 1:numel(frame)
     newframe=plus(avgframe,str2double(frame{jj}))/2;
     writeVideo(outputVideo,newframe);
     disp(['Frame ' num2str(jj)]);
 end
```

Is there a way I can edit the code so I do not have to use both loops?

Comment: what is the dimensions of `frame{ii}` ? is it an RGB image of grayscale?, why is it saved in strings?

Comment: They are RGB images that are 1024x1024. They are strings because I used uigetfile to retrieve the files.

Comment: RGB means they are 1024x1024x3 ...

Comment: Are they really cell arrays of strings? Yikes. That's going to be terribly inefficient I'd guess. There must be some other way. Can you at least convert the entire frame array in one call: `frame = str2double(frame);` (not sure if this works because I don't know what's actually in your cells)? Then you could do everything as doubles: `avgframe = mean(frame,1);` (the `1` might need to be a `2` or something else depending on `frame`).